# Switch statement won't reiterate counting

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement

The goal of this program is to create an array of values between 0 and 999 and then count how many values are within the ranges of [0,199], [200,399], [400, 599]... ect.

The problem is the switch statement will not continue the counting if the count has already occured.  (Note: have to use a switch statement)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int randN;
    int rand(); 
    int countOne = 0;
    int countTwo = 0;
    int countThree = 0;
    int countFour = 0;
    int countFive = 0;
    int countSix = 0;
    int *p1;


    printf("What is the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //MAKING THE N-size ARRAY 

    int array[n];
    int i;  
    for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
    {   
        randN=rand() % 999;
        array[i]=randN;

        p1=(int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int));
        p1[i]= array[i];

    }   

    //PRINTING THE N-size ARRAY  

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        printf("%i\n", array[i]);
    }   

    //SORTING THE N-size ARRAY 

    //Created this to avoid to solve a fragmentation problem 
    int p2[5] = {countOne, countTwo, countThree, countFour, countFive};

    for (i = 0 ;  i < n ; i++)
    {   
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                if(array[i] >= 0 && array[i] <=199)
                {
                    countOne++;
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                if(array[i] >= 200  && array[i] <= 399)
                {
                    countTwo++;
                    break;
                }
            case 3:
                if(array[i] >= 400 && array[i] <= 599)
                {
                    countThree++;
                    break;
                }
            case 4:
                if(array[i] >=600 && array[i] <= 799)
                {
                    countFour++;
                    break;
                }
            case 5:
                if(array[i] >=800 && array[i] <= 999)
                {
                    countFive++;
                    break;
                }

        }
    }
    printf("There is %d integers between 0 and 199\n", countOne);
    printf("There is %d integers between 200 and 399\n", countTwo);
    printf("There is %d integers between 400 and 599\n", countThree);
    printf("There is %d integers between 600 and 799\n", countFour);
    printf("There is %d integers between 800 and 999\n", countFive);

}
```

Output when entering '34'

What is the size of the array
34
823
7
347
587
184
953
672
188
161
955
828
719
762
359
909
164
52
277
43
298
744
478
792
254
508
636
789
963
62
637
952
272
689
298
There is 1 integers between 0 and 199
There is 1 integers between 200 and 399
There is 1 integers between 400 and 599
There is 0 integers between 600 and 799
There is 1 integers between 800 and 999

Comment: Honestly, the code just doesn't make any sense. What do you think `switch(i)` does? And why is it there? What is `p2` for? Why do you assign `p1` more than once?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code presented just doesn't bear any resemblance to code needed to perform the intended function, making the question unanswerable.

Comment: @David Schwartz The switch statement is there to switch through the cases for every value in the array.  P2 solved a fragmentation error, didn't mean to assign P1 twice.

Comment: The (ab)use of `p1` in the initialization loop means you are leaking memory ferociously.  It is not clear that you need `p1` at all; you certainly need to treat the memory allocated for it with a lot more respect.  The `p2` array is unused.  Neither of those affects your incorrect result.

Comment: The result is explainable. When `i==0`, none of the cases matches, so nothing is counted (823 is ignored). When `i==1`, `array[1]==7` which matches in `case 1`; when `i==2`, `array[2]==347` which matches in `case 2`; when `i==3`, `array[3]==587` which matches in `case 3`. However, when `i==4`, `array[4]==187` and it is skipped because the code checks with `case 4` and the value fails the test, and then flows to `case 5` and fails that test, so it is not counted. When `i==5`, `array[5]==953` and the result matches.  For all other values of `i`, no case matches (`i` is no longer range).

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but honestly, none of what you're saying makes any sense. You either need to learn how to use the C constructs that you're trying to use correctly or you need to talk to someone who can tease our your specific misunderstandings. What you're saying has no correspondence to the code or what you say you are trying to do, so I can't figure out how to correct whatever misconceptions you have. For example, I have no idea what you mean by a "fragmentation error" nor what you mean by "switch through the cases for every value in the array".

Comment: malloc() in the first for loop doesn't make any sense and there is no corresponding free().

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your code is not doing what you have mentioned in the question. Jonathan Leffler has explained why you are not getting output in his comment. I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int randN;
    int rand(); 
    int countOne = 0;
    int countTwo = 0;
    int countThree = 0;
    int countFour = 0;
    int countFive = 0;
    int countSix = 0;
    int *p1;


    printf("What is the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //MAKING THE N-size ARRAY 

    int array[n];
    int i;  
    for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
    {   
        randN=rand() % 999;
        array[i]=randN;

        /* MAYUR: These two lines are unnecessary and removing them. */
        //p1=(int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int));
        //p1[i]= array[i];

    }   

    //PRINTING THE N-size ARRAY  

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        printf("%i\n", array[i]);
    }   

    //SORTING THE N-size ARRAY //MAYUR: Why? btw, you are not sorting it here!

    //Created this to avoid to solve a fragmentation problem //MAYUR: What problem? I am removing it.
    //int p2[5] = {countOne, countTwo, countThree, countFour, countFive};

    for (i = 0 ;  i < n ; i++)
    {
        //MAYUR: You can categorize the number for given range values and use switch case.

        int tempCategory = array[i] / 100;
        switch(tempCategory)
        {
            //Equivalent to (array[i] >= 0 && array[i] <=199)
            case 0:
            case 1:
                {
                    countOne++;
                } break;

            //Equivalent to (array[i] >= 200 && array[i] <=399)
            case 2:
            case 3:
                {
                    countTwo++;
                } break;

            //Equivalent to (array[i] >= 400 && array[i] <=599)
            case 4:
            case 5:
                {
                    countThree++;
                } break;

            //Equivalent to (array[i] >= 600 && array[i] <=799)
            case 6:
            case 7:
                {
                    countFour++;
                } break;

            //Equivalent to (array[i] >= 800 && array[i] <=999)
            case 8:
            case 9:
                {
                    countFive++;
                } break;

            default:
                {
                    printf("Invalid number array[%d]=[%d] tempCategory[%d]\n", i, array[i], tempCategory);
                } break;

        }
    }
    printf("There is %d integers between 0 and 199\n", countOne);
    printf("There is %d integers between 200 and 399\n", countTwo);
    printf("There is %d integers between 400 and 599\n", countThree);
    printf("There is %d integers between 600 and 799\n", countFour);
    printf("There is %d integers between 800 and 999\n", countFive);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The thing is, you don't need to use switch case at all. You need to visit each element of the array once. Just a for loop is enough to do that. You have used the same technique to print out the elements of the array. The necessary code after removing the unwanted parts is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int n;
int randN;
int rand(); 
int countOne = 0;
int countTwo = 0;
int countThree = 0;
int countFour = 0;
int countFive = 0;
//int countSix = 0;
//int *p1;


printf("What is the size of the array\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

//MAKING THE N-size ARRAY 

int array[n];
int i;  
for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
{   
    randN=rand() % 999;
    array[i]=randN;

    // p1=(int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int));
    // p1[i]= array[i];

}   

//PRINTING THE N-size ARRAY  

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{   
    printf("%i\n", array[i]);
}   

//SORTING THE N-size ARRAY 

//Created this to avoid to solve a fragmentation problem 
// int p2[5] = {countOne, countTwo, countThree, countFour, countFive};

for (i = 0 ;  i < n ; i++)
{   
    if(array[i] >= 0  && array[i] <= 199 )
    {
        countOne++;

    }

    else if(array[i] >= 200  && array[i] <= 399)
    {
        countTwo++;

    }

    else if(array[i] >= 400 && array[i] <= 599)
    {
        countThree++;

    }

    else if(array[i] >=600 && array[i] <= 799)
    {
        countFour++;

    }

    else
    {
        countFive++;

    }
}
printf("There is %d integers between 0 and 199\n", countOne);
printf("There is %d integers between 200 and 399\n", countTwo);
printf("There is %d integers between 400 and 599\n", countThree);
printf("There is %d integers between 600 and 799\n", countFour);
printf("There is %d integers between 800 and 999\n", countFive);

}
```

I've checked the output and it is correct now.

Comment: I have to use a switch statement for this